# Combine a contour plot of a conic and an inset with an polygon such as all its vertices are on the conic

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a difficulty to programmatically adjust the size of a polygon within an inset of a conic (here I limit myself to a circle) in order to have all its vertices on the circle:

```
a = {-2, 0}; b = {2, 0}; c = {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}; d = {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[
2]}; e = {0, 2}; f = {0, -2};    
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 4 == 0}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, 
ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thin}, Frame -> None, Axes -> True, 
AspectRatio -> 1, Epilog ->
 {
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[a],   
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"a", a})},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point [b],
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"b", b})},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[c],
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"c", c})},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[d],
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"d", d})},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[e],
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"e", e})},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[f],
    (Text[Style[#1, 14], #2 + {-0.1, .1}] & @@ {"f", f})},
   {Inset[Graphics[
    {ColorData["Legacy", "Banana"], EdgeForm[{Thick, Pink}], 
     Opacity[0.15], Polygon[{a, b, c, d}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 4.2]},
   {Inset[Graphics[
    {ColorData["Legacy", "SlateBlue"], EdgeForm[{Thick, Pink}], 
     Opacity[0.15], Polygon[{a, e, c, f}]}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 3.6]}
 }]
```

Although the two polygons I defined here out of  six points have coordinates that are on the circle, I need to adjust the `size` parameter of the `Inset`, for every different position of a set of four points.
By trial an error I achieved something but far from satisfactory: I need to include the code above in a notebook under development where all the points are on the conic and dynamic and the polygon is constructed in the `Epilog` with these points.
Is there a way with MMA to compute the value of the `Inset size` parameter according to the vertices coordinates?

Comment: Yeah, why can't you just use Show, with the insets as separate graphics.

Comment: Why do you need to use `Inset[Graphics[...` instead of `Epilog->{Polygon[{a,b,c,d}]...`?

Comment: @Kuba Correct! I didn't think about using  `{ColorData["Legacy", "Banana"], EdgeForm[{Thick, Pink}], 
 Opacity[0.15], Polygon[{a, b, c, d}]}` in the `Epilog` instead of `Inset...` to achieve the same result. `Inset` obviously here was a wrong option and I guess that finding correctly the right `Size` would have been challenging and futile. I consider your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Kuba you should repost your comment as answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's shorter version:

```
a = {-2, 0}; b = {2, 0}; c = {Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}; d = {-Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}; e = {0, 2}; 
f = {0, -2};
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 - 4 == 0}, {x, -2.5, 2.5}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}, Axes -> True,  
            ContourStyle -> {Blue, Thin}, Frame -> None, AspectRatio -> 1, 
            Epilog -> {
 {ColorData["Legacy", "Banana"], EdgeForm[{Thick, Pink}], Opacity[0.15], 
  Polygon[{a, b, c, d}], ColorData["Legacy", "SlateBlue"], Polygon[{a, e, c, f}]},
 Blue, PointSize@.02, {Point@#2, Text[Style[#1, 18, Bold], 1.1 #2]} & @@@ {
  {"a", a}, {"b", b}, {"c", c}, {"d", d}, {"e", e}, {"f", f}}}]
```

[image]